# Search not working in Word Open File dialog

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, word

I'm in the Open File dialog box in Word 2013, listing files in a SP Foundation 2013 library.
The library contains hundreds of files, so I'd try using the search box, eg. entering the first characters of the file name, but it doesn't work: the list of document doesn't get filtered.

Even the predefined filters Last Modify and Size are not working.

What could it depends on?

I'm having the same issue with a list of libraries within a site: if I enter in the search box a portion of the name of a library, the list of libraries doesnt change.

**UPDATE**
I also tried appending * at the end of the search word, as suggested by Luís Eduardo Passos, but didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use * after entering the first characters of the file name.. They follow microsoft standard model. 
And in your library, you can only search for items who are Published, like 1.0, or 2.0. You can turn this option off, but it isn't advisable, because it can cause a lot of problems in the future.

Comment: Thank you, I tried but it gives no effects. All items are published.